# Any way to reduce the tangy taste of homemade coconut milk?

Tags: coffee, restaurant-mimicry, coconut

I make different kinds of non dairy milks (nut, rice, etc). I rather like coconut milk, but would like to reduce the natural tangy coconutty flavor.

I was looking at the following question:
[Homemade coconut milk in coffee compared to store bought](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33967/homemade-coconut-milk-in-coffee-compared-to-store-bought)

Someone was suggesting that the industry adds tri-calcium phosphate. I have no idea if that is available to the public or even if that would work. Any thoughts?

Edit: I believe my question is somewhat different from the one above as it doesn't specifically relate to coffee. I think this small factor might influence the answers. This question has generated different answers to the question.

Comment: So... your question title sounds like a duplicate of the question you've linked to. Is your actual question "can an individual buy tri-calcium phosphate?"

Comment: Your partly right, but there might be other options too. If not, then the question would be "can an individual buy tri-calcium phosphate?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homemade coconut milk in coffee compared to store bought](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33967/homemade-coconut-milk-in-coffee-compared-to-store-bought)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best method is simply to heat the coconut.

My current method:

- Heat shredded coconut and water (1:4 ratio). No need to boil.
- Let the mixture cool. I usually forget about it and come back a few hours later
- Blend and strain

Although someone had pointed out to me that tricalcium phosphate is used in commercial brands, today I would tell them this is a bad idea.

I have now tasted about every brand available to me and they all taste pretty awful. The worst in terms of taste have tricalcium phosphate.

Homemade is truly the best. Just use a bit of heat to mellow out the taste.

<strike>I have experimented with baking soda. This works rather well, however it does leave a taste/sensation of its own. Although I didn't put much I will try to use less the next time. Nonetheless, I am submitting this as an answer. I will try to get my hands on tricalcium phosphate -- if I can -- and report back.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

In Indonesia (and I assume neighbouring countries too) they simply adjust coconut milk (they call it santen) to the level of coconuttiness they want.

So: 
Soak coconut shavings/scrapings in hot water and squeeze and filter it through a muslin (santen asli/murni). You want less coconutty? Soak the previously soaked & squeezed coconut shavings/scrapings *again* in the same amount of hot water (santen cair). Repeat until satisfied. There's at least two levels down from "santen cair" that I know of: "santen kedua", and "santen ketiga", the last one would we soaked-squeezed-resoaked-squeezed-resoaked-squeezed-resoaked-squeezed coconut milk. The water to coconut meat ratio they use is about a liter per kilogram of scrapings, roughly a cup of water per 250 grams.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Willem. However, one this that doesn't appeal to me is that you are effectively watering down the solution and reducing the nutritional value.

Comment: No worries, I understand. Made this way, it is probably indeed more of a flavoring ingredient than a nutritional one. In stores here you can also buy a thickened down variant, but it tends to be too greasy. Out of curiosity, how *do* you make yours?

Comment: By hand with muslin like you suggested, but only the first extraction. However, I am looking into building a hydraulic press for better extraction.